# win bat file to read txt file and output as new file dependant on field in line 2 onwards

Tags: file, csv, batch-file, skip

I am writing a script to read a list of files from a folder

I need to ignore the first line (but keep)
read lines 2+ and write (first line) and lines 2+ on out to a new file dependant on field 8

```
for /r %%a in (*) do (
echo %%a >>D:\Scripts\Cash_Files\list_Files.txt
)

for /f "tokens=5 delims=\" %%a in (D:\Scripts\Cash_Files\list_Files.txt) do (
for /f "skip=1 tokens=1-8 delims=," %%k in (%%a) do (
>>"%%k-CHQS-%%a.csv" echo(*
)
)
```

data file in

```
Cheque Number,Sort Code,Account Number,Amount £,Payee Reference,Payment Reference (Ifactor),RA Amount £,Currency
123456,123456,12345678,100.00,ABCDEFG,1234/123456,100.00,GBP
123456,123456,12345678,10.00,ABCABC,5678/987654,102.00,EUR
123456,123456,12345678,1.00,AABBCC,1234/123456,1.00,GBP
```

I would like to write line 1 plus lines 2 and 4 out to a file called GBP-data.csv
and line 1 plus line 3 out to a file called EUR-data.csv

at the moment I am creating files called

123456-CHQS_filename.csv and the contents is only '*'

Comment: Seems like you are handicapping yourself by specifying what lines you want.  What I think you are really trying to explain is that you want the file split by the Currency type and create new files based on the currency type.

Comment: Currently it isn't clear what the fifth token is supposed to be at your first `For` loop, it may help if you revise your question.

Comment: @Compo, I think the user is misusing the `FOR /R` command and is really only getting the contents of a single directory.  I am thinking the 5th token is their file name since they are using the \ as a delimiter.  But as you and I both know that is not necessary and the user should really read the help for the `FOR` command and use the command modifiers to get the file name.